# Ascii graphic interface library (ncurses-like) for emacs scripts?

Tags: emacs, elisp, ncurses, ascii-art

Is there any interface library for emacs scripts, allowing to draw various gui in emacs buffers?

As far as I know, emacs extensions interface is limited by key-bindings and dialogues in the message buffer.
At the same time, you can draw anything in a buffer (artist-mode), and can react on any user action (keyboard and mouse-clicks) so it is surely possibly, to implement such library entirely in elisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [Emacs Widget Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/widget/index.html). It has editable fields, buttons, menus, etc - all in text mode. For instance

```
(widget-create 'editable-field
                  :size 13
                  :format "Name: %v " ; Text after the field!
                  "My Name")
```